# Categories generated by a single object

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Are there any interesting examples of categories generated by a single object? By this I mean the following. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and let $\star \in Ob(\mathcal{C})$. Create a new category $\mathcal{D}$ whose objects are $\star$ and formal (co)limits $F:I \to \mathcal{C}$ such that $F(i)=\star$ for all $i \in I$ (with no restriction on morphisms). We say that $\mathcal{D}$ is *generated* by $\star$. Do any categories we know arise in this way?

$\textbf{EDIT}:$ I think I'd prefer to drop the term "formal" from my question. I'd rather think about (co)limits that occur in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Do you allow $I$ to vary ?

Comment: Aside (?): one usually means [something different by "generators" of a category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(category_theory)). And that something different [isn't the same as everything being a colimit of a diagram whose vertices are generators](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204792/is-every-abelian-group-a-colimit-of-copies-of-z).

Comment: @Pece Yes I can be any indexing category

Answer (score 1):

For any (small) category $\mathcal{A}$, the category of "formal colimits of diagrams in $\mathcal{A}$"  is equivalent to the presheaf category $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set})$. (I assume you intend for the *morphisms* of $\mathcal{D}$ to be the ones freely generated by the condition that the objects become *actual* colimits in $\mathcal{D}$)

In your problem, $\mathcal{A}$ is the full subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$ spanned by the object $\star$. (I assume $\mathcal{C}$ is locally small)

In the case (such as yours) where $\mathcal{A}$ is a category with one object (which I will call $\star$), the presheaf category has an alternate description: $\hom(\star, \star)$ is a monoid $M_\mathcal{A}$, and $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{A}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set})$ is equivalent to the category of right $M_{\mathcal{A}}$-sets. (i.e. sets with a right action by the monoid $M_\mathcal{A}$)

---

The category of "formal limits" is obtained by dualizing: $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{A}, \mathbf{Set})^\mathrm{op}$.

Comment: Hm I'm thinking I shouldn't have included the term "formal." I'm thinking of a situation roughly as follows. Consider the multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_m$ in the category of commutative group schemes, and take all (co)limits inside that category generated by $\mathbb{G}_m$. In particular, this category will include $0$. It will also include things like $\alpha_p$, when working in prime characteristic